# how/where to grab compiler of msvs 2008 (32bit) compiler toolchain without installing msvs2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008, toolchain

I'm relatively new-comer to developing in windows ("7") and the environment that has been set up for me is using as IDE MS Visual Studio 2015. For a new project I'll be involved in I will work with a team who have been developing in Visual Studio 2008 a 32bit application.

As I try to create the development environment using `cmake` and selecting as target compiler "Visual Studio 9 2008" , cmake whines that

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (project):
  No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (project):
  No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.
```

So I would need to obtain the respective toolchain. I have no idea how to do that in windows though and google (at least with the search terms I have used) has not been very helpful.

Note: The IDE of the team is indeed old but it is not an option to ask all of them to migrate now to a newer version.

Note2: As I understand, I cannot obtain a license for "Visual Studio 2008" anymore, but even if this is not the case, I would prefer to continue using visual studio 2015 even while developing this project. Is it possible to just obtain the compiler toolchain of 2008 and integrate it somehow so that 
1) cmake can find it
2) visual studio 2015 can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way to go would be to install Visual studio 2008 Express if you can find the installer. It is free, and you can use its compiler without using the IDE.
In cmake you can separately select target IDE version (generator) and target compilers (toolchain).
AFAIK there was no separate download just for the compilers but there were some bundles which include it and you can try your luck with them if you can't/don't want to install full VS2008 installation (cmake might have some difficulties finding this versions though).

- "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7" package should contain just the compiler/libraries part of the VS 2008
- "Windows SDK 6.1" and "Windows SDK 7.0" (but not "Windows SDK 7.1") include a version of the compiler which should be compatible with VS2008